# MFP 8 Server Maintenance

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any default way to enable/disable maintenance in MFP 8 ? So that, App should not be accessible. Also, if MFP is down, what's the default message to check UNRESPONSIVE_HOST or UNKNOWN_ERROR ? Pl help !

Comment: You can use remote disable feature to disable the app to access the server.

Comment: but i want to capture the response from MFP and show some MAINTENANCE page to the customer. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enable maintenance in MFP 8 from the app, it can only be done from the mfp server console only. Workaround -  You can put custom Pop up in error callback for every call made to the MFP server.